# Broken link for Google NGrams when an apostrophe is involved

Tags: google-ngram-viewer

If I do a search for "Bartholomew's day massacre" from `https://books.google.com/ngrams`, I get to `https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Bartholomew%27s+day+massacre&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBartholomew%20%27s%20day%20massacre%3B%2Cc0`. 
If I copy that into my web browser, I am told

> No valid ngrams to plot!
>      Ngrams not found: Bartholomew 's day massacre, [Bartholomew 's day massacre]

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some testing, the following works:

```
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Bartholomew's+day+massacre&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=
```

It appears you need to remove the direct_url parameter. Actually, your original link works. You just have to select the text box and press Enter. This might be a temporary bug.